# How to apply custom string matching function to pandas dataframe and return summary dataframe about correct/ incorrect patterns?

Tags: pandas, function, arguments, data-cleaning, verification

I have written a pattern matching function to classify weather a dataframe column value matches a given pattern or not. I created a column 'Correct_Pattern' to store the boolean answers in that dataframe. I also created a new dataframe called Incorrect_Pattern_df, which only contains the values that do not match the desired pattern. I did this, because I later on would like to see if I can correct those incorrect numbers. Now, every time I corrected a batch of numbers I would like to check the number format again and regenerate the Incorrect_Pattern_df. Please see my code below. What do I need to do to  make it work?

```
#data
mylist = ['850/07-498745', '850/07-148465', '07-499015']

#create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(mylist)
df.rename(columns={ df.columns[0]: "mycolumn" }, inplace = True)


#function to check if my numbers follow the correct pattern
def check_number_format(dataframe, rm_pattern, column_name):

#create a column Correct_pattern that contains a boolean 'true or false' depending wheather the 
pattern was matched or not
dataframe['Correct_pattern'] = dataframe[column_name].str.match(pattern)

#filter all incorrect patterns and put them in a dataframe called Incorrect-Pattern_df
Incorrect_Pattern_df = dataframe[dataframe.Correct_pattern == False]

#return both the original dataframe with the added Correct_pattern_df and the dataframe containing 
the Incorrect_Pattern_df 
return Incorrect_Pattern_df

#apply the check_Schadennumer_Format to a dataframe
Incorrect_Pattern_df = df['mycolumn'].apply(check_number_format,  args=(df, r'^\d{2}-\d+$', 
'mycolumn'))
```

The desired output should look as follows:

[image]

Comment: `df['mycolumn'].str.match(your_pattern_here)`?

Comment: Hello @QuangHoang. Thank you for your answer. You are right, I over-complicated it !